# Is there a Java library equivalent to Microsoft/.NET System.IO.Packaging?

Tags: java, system.io.packaging, open-packaging-convention

Is there a Java library equivalent to [`System.IO.Packaging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx). If so what is the experience of

1. unpacking DOCX files
2. editing DOCX files
3. building DOCX files from scratch.

Comment: It would be nice if you linked to the namespace in question in the future so that people who only know Java have a chance of answering.

Comment: @Joachim I believe this IS the namespace.I also included the SO tag for system.io.packaging. I assume you edited the link to the MS URL - if so thanks

Comment: @01 @willcode thanks for the links. Both of these point to rather moribund projects (openxml4j.org doesn't respond and plutext was last edited 11 months ago). More recent news would be valuable - do people use these pakages today?

Comment: Yes, I meant the URL. Of course you mention the namespace, I was asking for a URL to the documentation that we can find out what it actually does (because "Packaging" can mean any number of things).

Comment: I was too hasty and unfair to plutext - it has an active forum and has recently released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend docx4j which you can find here: http://dev.plutext.org/trac/docx4j
It is a library for creating/unpacking/editing docx files and also lets you convert them to html, pdf etc.

Answer (score 0):

this should help you
[InfoQ: Using Java to Crack Office 2007](http://www.infoq.com/articles/cracking-office-2007-with-java)